# Spring Roo - Database Reverse Engineer freezes

Tags: database, spring-mvc, spring-roo

We are new spring-roo but very familiar with RAD on PHP using Yii & Active Record. 
I was able to run roo> database reverse engineer --schema to create models off an Oracle database for a proof of concept I am working on. The command line freezes since the 3rd attempt to update the schema. The difference between the first two attempts and the 3rd one is that we used the --includeTables option without knowing that it would overwrite the entire dbre.xml (instead of doing an incremental change). We have cleaned the cache and even reinstalled roo but the issue persists. Even creating a new project did not help. I can see the following in spring-roo logs:

// Spring Roo 1.3.2.RELEASE [rev 8387857] log opened at 2016-04-13 19:39:41
database properties list
// [failed] database reverse engineer --schema pfadmin --package ~.domain

Any idea or help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution after half a day of investigation. Spring roo performs an analyze table while reverse engineering the models. If your database is very large, then the compute statistics will take a long long long time :D 
My advise export the database as DDL only not data, create an empty development database and run spring roo against to get your models.